# serde_json serializer not working for structs defined in certain crates

Tags: javascript, serialization, webassembly, rust-cargo, serde-json

In the process of testing these web assembly [bindings](https://github.com/zkonduit/ezkl/blob/main/src/wasm.rs)
in this tutorial [application](https://github.com/zkonduit/wasm-tutorial-web/tree/build--rebuild-wasm-tutorial-app-in-next.js) I discovered an issue with the serializers in this [crate](https://github.com/zkonduit/ezkl/blob/main/src/wasm.rs#L10C4-L10C4) whenever I tested them in a JS environment.

For context, here is how I discovered the issue:

At first I realized the elgamalEncrypt binding was failing for the wasm tutorial... I fixed the issue by changing

```
 pub fn elgamalEncrypt(
    pk: wasm_bindgen::Clamped<Vec<u8>>,
    message: wasm_bindgen::Clamped<Vec<u8>>,
    r: wasm_bindgen::Clamped<Vec<u8>>,
) -> Vec<u8> {
    let pk: G1Affine = serde_json::from_slice(&pk[..]).unwrap();
    let message: Vec<Fr> = serde_json::from_slice(&message[..]).unwrap();
    let r: Fr = serde_json::from_slice(&r[..]).unwrap();

    let output = crate::circuit::modules::elgamal::ElGamalGadget::encrypt(pk, message, r);

    serde_json::to_vec(&output).unwrap()
}
```

to this

```
/// Encrypt using elgamal in browser. Input message
#[wasm_bindgen]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub fn elgamalEncrypt(
    pk: wasm_bindgen::Clamped<Vec<u8>>,
    message: wasm_bindgen::Clamped<Vec<u8>>,
    r: wasm_bindgen::Clamped<Vec<u8>>,
) -> Vec<u8> {
    let pk: [[u64; 4]; 2] = serde_json::from_slice(&pk[..]).unwrap();
    let pk: G1Affine = G1Affine {
        x: Fq::from_raw(pk[0]),
        y: Fq::from_raw(pk[1]),
    };
    let message: Vec<[u64; 4]> = serde_json::from_slice(&message[..]).unwrap();
    let message: Vec<Fr> = message.iter().map(|b| vecu64_to_field(b)).collect();
    let r: [u64; 4] = serde_json::from_slice(&r[..]).unwrap();
    let r: Fr = vecu64_to_field(&r);

    let output = crate::circuit::modules::elgamal::ElGamalGadget::encrypt(pk, message, r);

    serde_json::to_vec(&output).unwrap()
}
```

And that stopped that binding from failing.
But then the [elgamalDecrypt](https://github.com/zkonduit/ezkl/blob/main/src/wasm.rs#L64C8-L64C22) wasn't properly decrypting the message anymore in the wasm tutorial application...

Ultimately I ended up "fixing" the issue in this PR [here](https://github.com/zkonduit/ezkl/pull/396) by essentially replicating the functionality of [these serializers](https://github.com/zkonduit/ezkl/blob/main/src/wasm.rs#L10C4-L10C4) in the wasm binding.

The reason why we haven't merged these changes yet is because it feels like we're putting a bandaid on a deeper issue. The changes definitely make sense if the serializer isn't being called, but ultimately we need to figure out why the serde_json serializer is not triggering properly.